# Sort by Type → folder and all its sub folder

Tags: windows-7, sorting, file-types

[image]

Below is a GIF that shows sort by type on a subfolder of the main folder. The main folder has many subfolders and deeper layers can the sort by type be applied in one go on the entire folder and its subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can achieve this with the Windows File Explorer.

However, you could achieve what you are looking for using Everything by https://www.voidtools.com/.  It allows you to structure searching by Match Path and/or filenames and common file types.  If you combine a search using Match Path with the column sorting you can achieve your objective regardless of the deep nested folders.

Everything supports boolean operators or even Regular Expressions so you can get pretty creative with your file searching and organizing by using both Match Path in addition to partial/full filenames or types.  It's incredibly powerful and you can almost obsolete using Windows File Explorer to locate and organize your files.

Comment: Thanks for your support and Inputs. Lets wait maybe someone can give some alternative insight.